# conditional operator to setState

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, state, operator-keyword, setstate

I have a button for pagination in my React component in render function. Can you help me to convert this conditional operator to setState? I have a lot of this yellow bugs in console trough conditional operator. I need to use it but I don't know how to use setState with it.

```
<button onClick={() => this.makeHttpRequestWithPage(this.state.current_page < this.state.total_pages ? this.state.current_page + 1 : this.state.current_page = this.state.total_pages)}>&raquo;</button>
```

> Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()

Comment: You do not need to setState for this to work: `this.makeHttpRequestWithPage(this.state.current_page < this.state.total_pages ? this.state.current_page + 1 : this.state.total_pages)`

Comment: He has to update the current page once you goes to the next page

Comment: @colburton, yes, this works well without setState but I get yellow warning in the console ''Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()"

Comment: We can't see what `makeHttpRequestWithPage` does, there might be more state manipulation. If you use my version you are no longer changing the state.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the concept of "immutability" in JavaScript.

Basically, if i have an immutable JS object, lets say state is:

```
state = {
    name: "Dimitar",
    age: 18,
    hobbies: ["Programming", "Watching TV shows", "Studying"]
}
```

I cant directly mutate it this way:

```
state.name = "Something Else"
```

The object itself can be reassigned, but its values are set (constant). To get around this, React has created the setState function which basically makes a copy of the previous state object, reassigns new values to it and then overwrites the previous object.

So if you want to mutate the state, or alter its contents then you need to use the setState in such fashion:

```
setState({
     name: "Dimitar2"
})
```

Here, you can also pass the prevState as a parameter and use it, but i will let you do the research on that. Also, you can use the spread operator etc.

Comment: This is not accurate. You can change state. JS is totally fine with it. It's React's render magic inside setState which make it necessary to never change the state directly.

Comment: @colburton do you know why it is not recomanded to change immutable variables in javascript? Obviously it is possible to change the value of an immutable object, but not without getting a big fat warning in the console.

Comment: FYI, an immutable object (unchangeable object) is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created. Those are not my words, its in the documentation. State IS an Immutable object. Its contents cannot be mutated, and the only way to change them is by object reassignment:
oldObj = updatedObj
Which happens under the hood of setState if you dig around:
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() => 
this.setState({current_page: this.state.current_page < this.state.total_pages ? this.state.current_page + 1 : this.state.current_page}, () => this.makeHttpRequestWithPage(this.state.currentPage);)}>&raquo;</button>
```

Here you first update the current page based on the condition and after state is set you make the call.

Comment: looks good, bu I get warning:

Warning: setState(...): Expected the last optional `callback` argument to be a function. Instead received: [object Promise].

Comment: warning is gone but the page does not display correctly
by default I have current_page: 1, total_pages: 2
after click i got current_page: 0

Comment: Can you share your code? current_page shouldn't hit 0 ideally

Comment: Maybe some part of code but tomorrow. Thank you all for helping